# How to give a solution to this error > Task :app:installDebug FAILED? Can someone explain me , please?

Tags: android, react-native

I new in react-native, its is my first time using this. But I've searched several solution in the internet but I couldn't find any one witch could really help me. 
I installed Android Studio, Nodejs, react-Native CLI, npm, Visual Studio so everything that needed to work with. I created Android Virtual Device Emulator so that I can see my Project in the Virtual Phone. But I still having this error.
My errors in CMD:

```
> Task :app:installDebug FAILED
Skipping device 'emulator-5554' (emulator-5554): Device is OFFLINE.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No online devices found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 5s
28 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 27 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Comment: you need to start an android emulator before running the project

Comment: Before writing questions directly on StackOverflow at least try doing some research on your own, even the solution is clearly visible in the logs

`* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No online devices found.`
If you have done research already please provide valid links which questions doesn't work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the Android Emulator. Changed the AVD settings to enable "Use Host GPU" and the issue was resolved.

This is a problem with the Android SDK being super slow sometimes:

ShellCommandUnresponsiveException means installing the APK (simply running adb install) timed out
No online devices found means the emulator went into a bad state and is not responding to any adb commands
Using the host GPU and hardware acceleration (HAXM on OSX / Windows, KVM on Linux) usually helps with this.

OR switching to " Genymotion ".

Answer (score 0):

Emulator is not live. Re-run the emulator or use a physical android device or might be there is some issue with adb